# supabase 403 error when trying to insert into table

Tags: supabase

i have got a vue/supabase project that all im trying to do is register a user and add their details to a table. When trying to register the auth works and adds the email to the auth. The user can also log I'n as that works but when registering I try and add the email and username to a table and it keeps giving me a

```
POST https://vumblwlvddvktzbqrfkm.supabase.co/rest/v1/profiles?columns=%22username%22%2C%22email%22 403
```

Error.
[image]
the table is simple, it has email and user name columns that are text and the id is linked to the auth id.
This is my add to table code which gives the 403 error:

```
 const addtoTable = async () => {
        try{
          const {data,error} = await supabase.from('profiles').insert([{username: username.value, email: email.value}], {returning: 'minimal'});
          if(error)throw error;
          alert("account added to table");
        }catch(error){ alert(error);}
      };
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to manually add new users directly to the table?

Comment: yes as that table is different to the auth table that automatically gets added

Comment: This was solved on https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/9335